# Javascript function code issue

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if I could get peoples input. I'm taking a javascript class doing basic coding. We just started going over functions and I can't get my results to return.

I made two programs:

3.1 is supposed to take the 3 numbers given from the prompts and return the smallest and largest number:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Even to Odd</title>
        <script>
 // Program name: Assignment 3.1
// Purpose: Finds smallest and largest numbers
// Author: Eric Messihi
// Date last modified: 09-Mar-2018
        function oddEven(num){
         if(num%2==0)
                {
                document.write('the number is Even.');
                }
            else
                {
                document.write('the number is Odd.');    
                }   
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
        //variables
            var num;
            
        //prompts for integers
            num = parseInt(prompt('Hi! Pick a number, any number', ""));
            
            // Call the module, display the result
            
        
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

3.2 is supposed to take the number given and indicate wether the number is even or odd:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Smallest to Largest</title>
        <script>
// Program name: Assignment 3.1
// Purpose: Finds smallest and largest numbers
// Author: Eric Messihi
// Date last modified: 09-Mar-2018
        function min(n1, n2, n3){
            //declare variable
            var smallest;
            smallest = n1
       if (n2 < smallest) {
           smallest = n2;
       }
       if (n3 < smallest) {
           smallest = n3;
       }
            return min;
            }
        function max(n1, n2, n3){
            //declare variable
            var largest;
            largest = n1
       if (n2 > largest) {
        largest = n3;
       }
       if (n3 > largest) {
        largest = n3;
       }
            return max;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
//variables
            var n1, n2, n3;
            var min = "";
            var max = "";
//prompts for integers
n1 = parseInt(prompt('Hi! What is your first number?', ""));
 n2 = parseInt(prompt('Great! What is your second number?', ""));
 n3 = parseInt(prompt('Almost done! What is your third number?', ""));
   
        // Call the four modules, display the results
    min = smallest;
   document.write("The smallest of the three numbers is: " + min);
    max = largest;
   document.write("The largest of the three numbers is: " + max);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you forget calling your methods which returns results?

Comment: My apologies everyone, the codes got switched.

Comment: @G_S I feel like that must be the case, at least for the smallest and largest number code.

Comment: So you still have issues with it to make it work? or are you good?

Comment: @G_S still having issues...I'm assuming this is an easy fix but I'm new to coding and I can't seem to find where I went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Even to Odd</title>
        <script>
 // Program name: Assignment 3.1
// Purpose: Finds smallest and largest numbers
// Author: Eric Messihi
// Date last modified: 09-Mar-2018
        function oddEven(num){
         if(num%2==0)
                {
                document.write('the number is Even.');
                }
            else
                {
                document.write('the number is Odd.');    
                }   
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
        //variables
            var num;
            
        //prompts for integers
            num = parseInt(prompt('Hi! Pick a number, any number', ""));
             oddEven(num)
            // Call the module, display the result
            
        
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Smallest to Largest</title>
  <script>
    // Program name: Assignment 3.1
    // Purpose: Finds smallest and largest numbers
    // Author: Eric Messihi
    // Date last modified: 09-Mar-2018
    function getmin(n1, n2, n3) {
      //declare variable
      var smallest;
      smallest = n1
      if (n2 < smallest) {
        smallest = n2;
      }
      if (n3 < smallest) {
        smallest = n3;
      }
      
      return smallest;
    }

    function getmax(a, b, c) {
      //declare variable
      var largest;
      
      if (a>b  && a>c)
      {
      return a;
      }

      if (b>a  && b>c)
      {
        return b;
      }

      else
      {
        return c;
      }
      
      
      return largest;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //variables
    var n1, n2, n3;
    var min = "";
    var max = "";
    //prompts for integers
    n1 = parseInt(prompt('Hi! What is your first number?', ""));
    n2 = parseInt(prompt('Great! What is your second number?', ""));
    n3 = parseInt(prompt('Almost done! What is your third number?', ""));

    // Call the four modules, display the results
    min = getmin(+n1, +n2, +n3);
    document.write("The smallest of the three numbers is: " + min);
    max = getmax(n1, n2, n3);
    document.write("The largest of the three numbers is: " + max);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The issue with your code is the fact that you are overriding the function definition of min and max with your local variables. So when you try to call the function, its saying min/max is not a function(because local min/max variables are overriding the function behavior.

Tried changing function names and its working.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for your help, @G_S ! I was still having issues getting the numbers returned and I realized my return was different that the variable defined in the function but I fixed that.